# All Network in ubuntu 14 have been removed and can't connect to internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

[Information about Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTdRR.png)

Dears,

As per screenshot , all network in my laptop have been removed suddenly , and I can't connect to internet.

Would you please support !

*lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2*

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380b]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Done , and kindly see the output :


01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380b]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]

Comment: What did you do before this happened? Did you install any kernels?

Comment: Actually , I don't remember , the issue from long time.

Comment: Please hook up the ethernet and run the command: `sudo modprobe r8169` Now does ethernet appear in the Network Manager icon? Please then run: `ifconfig` and post the result.

Comment: Kindly see the output ,
sudo modprobe r8169  ->>>
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:686 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'
modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found.

Comment: ifconfig  ->>>>
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:827445 (827.4 KB)  TX bytes:827445 (827.4 KB)

Comment: As you do not have an ath10k device, let's remove the file and try again: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf` and then: `sudo modprobe r8169` Please post the result.

Comment: The first command executed Successfully, the result of the second command is : modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found

Comment: Wow! You have a real mystery there! Let's dig deeper: `sudo updatedb && locate r816 | grep .ko` As the output may be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I ran the command "sudo updatedb && locate r816 | grep .ko" , but there is no output.

Comment: WOW! How about: `uname -a` and also: `arch`

Comment: uname -a  ->>>>
Linux rabab-Lenovo-Z50-70 3.13.0-68-generic #111-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
************
arch->>>>
x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download these packages on some other computer: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-3.13.0-70-generic_3.13.0-70.113_amd64.deb

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-70-generic_3.13.0-70.113_amd64.deb

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-3.13.0-70_3.13.0-70.113_all.deb

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-extra-3.13.0-70-generic_3.13.0-70.113_amd64.deb

Transfer them on a USB key or similar to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer. Now, in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Desktop/linux*.deb
```

Reboot.

Post back any errors or missing dependencies. Once we have networking, we will have additional steps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52454/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-all-network-in-ubuntu-14-have-been-removed-and).

Comment: I can add the optional solution - usually there is older kernel with headers and extra and with the internet working. At the boot time choosing previous kernel. So, it is not necessary to search another way to download installation files.